# Is it possible to set a scope for ValidationSummaryControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validationsummary

Can I set a scope for the asp.Net ValidationSummary control so that it only validates the contents of a particular asp.net panel?

My goal is to have 2 different validaitonsummary controls for different panels on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set the [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.validationgroup.aspx) property on your summary and on the controls which you want to summarise.

This is just an arbitrary string, so as long as they all match, you have created a group!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the **ValidationGroup** property.

All the ASP controls have this property.